# Java, Call overridden method implicitly

Tags: java, inheritance, oop

Right now in some Java code I have something like this

```
class A {
 void f() {

 }
 A() {
  f();
 }
}

class B extends A{
 @Override
 void f() {
  //do some stuff
  super.f();
 }
}

class C extends B {
 @Override
 void f() {
  //do some stuff
  super.f();
 }
}
```

I want to have `f()` called and then iterate upwards through each parent class, running the overridden `f()`. I do this by calling `super.f()` explicitly, although I'd like to not have to do this.

The reason why I do this is there post processing that must be done after the constructor in A is reached. And there is state in each class that much be properly init'd, which is why we have the upward trace of `f()`'s.

So the constructor of `A` is really

```
A() {
  //init some state in a
  f(); //run f(), which will depend on the previous operation
}
```

If I do something like `new C();` I want `C.f()` called, then `B.f()` called, then `A.f()` called

Anyway, if there is a smarter way of doing this, I'm open to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling non-final methods in a constructor is generally a bad idea - at the very least, I'd suggest you document it *heavily*. Bear in mind that when f() is called, C's constructor won't have been called - and neither will any variable initializers. The object is only half-initialized, and so methods will need to be written very carefully.

There's no way of implicitly calling `super.f()` though in normal Java. Given the large warnings I'd be putting around that code, a single statement is far from the end of the world :)

If you want to verify that it's called, you could always check for the results of `A.f()` in A's constructor immediately after the call - that will check that the call has reached the top level.

Comment: +1 for "Calling non-final methods in a constructor is generally a bad idea" (from experience :-)

Comment: I don't need any of the constructors to have been run, as long as the first part of A() is executed, we're in good shape. This is part of a hack to do serialization without using the Serialization interface by using a private namespace. Basically all classes declare the variables they are going to use beforehand, but A init's the private namespace. Thanks for the reply Jon, I figured this wasn't possible, nice to have a second opinion

Comment: Still, it's sometimes attractive to use template method pattern in constructors. As long as abstract (or non-final) methods implement algorithm without relying on state it works. Another solution is using lazy initialization. I have a blog exactly on this issue: http://novyden.blogspot.com/2011/08/java-anti-pattern-constructors-and.html

Answer (score 4):

This may help you somewhat - it's a way to enforce that the child class calls the super; this would help you detect developer mistakes where the implementer of a child class forgot to continue the call up the chain to super.f():

```
class A {
 boolean fDone;

 public final void f() {
  fDone = false;
  doF();
  if (!fDone) {
   throw new IllegalStateException("super.f() was not called");
  }
 }

 protected void doF() {
  //do some operation
  fDone = true;
 }
}

class B extends A {
 protected void doF() {
  //some operation, maybe repeat this pattern of using a flag to enforce super call
  super.doF();
 }
}
```

So, the child overrides doF(), but is required to call super.doF();

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no way to do this.  AspectJ might do something similar to this, but then you'd have to tag it with an annotation, I suppose, which is hardly less work than just calling `super.f()`.  You need to signify that the superclass method is being called, because you need to have the ability to make that decision for each subclass separately - otherwise, you might have a subclass that doesn't want to delegate anything to the superclass at all - so the default is that you just put in the code.