# Use derived type for member variable in derived class

Tags: java, oop, gwt, object-oriented-analysis

I currently have a class A that has some functionalities that I'd like to use in B. And A has a member variable of type Button, while in B I want to use the type IconButton (derived from Button).

The classes are like this:

```
public class A {

    protected Button x = new Button();

    A() {
        x.xx();
    }

    public void doFirstThing() {
        x.xx();
    }

    Button getButton() {
        return x;
    }
}

public class B extends A {

    B() {
        x = new IconButton();

        getButton().yy();
    }

    public void doSecondThing() {
        getButton().zz();
    }

    IconButton getButton() {
        return (IconButton) x;
    }
}

public class Button {

    public void xx() {

    }   
}

public class IconButton extends Button {

    public void yy() {

    }

    public void zz() {

    }
}
```

As you can see, methods `yy()` and `zz()` are only available in `IconButton`, thus I need to do the "workaround" in B by providing a method `getButton`.

And yes, normally we'd have a `getButton()` method in A too, so this is not a far-fetched addition to B.

But I'm wondering, is this really the right way to do or I'm doing it wrong ?

I have also thought of creating an abstract class, e.g. A0, that would contain the current code from A. Then I'd just make:

```
class A extends A0<Button> {
 // mostly empty, code taken from A0
}

class B extends A0<IconButton> {
// custom things here
}
```

Or are there other ways that are really better for this problem ?

This is a Component in my GWT app. So, if I declare like @king_nak said, then I'll have two buttons in my component. Or if I can live with yet another workaround, I can remove the original button in B, e.g. `x.removeFromParent()` or something like that, but then it'd just become a whole new level of bad practice.

Comment: what about `abstract class A<T extends Button>` with a field `T x`, and `class B extends A<IconButton>`?

Comment: I'm not sure if you intend to construct an instance of class `A` at some moment. If so, then it's ok'ish, except `IconButton getButton()` is not required. If you won't create an instance of `A` , then  make it abstract yes

Comment: The IconButton is a implementation detail of B. Why expose IconeButton and Button to the clients of these classes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You workaround is a bad idea. You loose a lot of typesafety. You could e.g. change the construtor of `B` to `x = new Button();` and forget about the cast. Your program would still compile but fail at runtime.

I think you are on the right track with the common generic superclass. You could define `A0` as `A0<T extends Button>` with a member `T x`. There might be a better solution but it's hard to tell without the big picture.

Comment: I have updated my question with more specifics about my usecase. It's a GWT app (A and B are really components), and yy() and zz() need to be used in many places inside A and B too. Do you have any more suggestions about this case ?

Comment: @ramcrys no, I'm no GWT expert. To thoroughly answer this question in the big picture this would become to broad for stackoverflow.

Comment: Accepted the answer :) I already went with the generics approach in my code. Will have to observe how it fares in the future.

Answer (score 0):

An easy (and polymorphic) way would be to override `getButton` in class B and return an instance of `IconButton` instead of having a reference in the class at all, e.g.:

```
public class A {
    public Button getButton(){
        Button b = new Button();
        b.xx();
        return b;
    }
}

public class B extends A {

    @Override
    public Button getButton(){
        IconButton b = new IconButton();
        b.yy();
        b.zz();
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: In this situation, there are some factory design patterns which leads to a more cleaner code if you ask me.

Comment: If the type of instance returned by `getButton` method depends on the class that overrides it then I would rather go with this way than implementing factory methods.

Comment: Why doing that if the type (that depends on the class) is being inherited from `Button`  at all? A clean approach is an interface but i'm not certain in this situation because I don't see the OP's indent cleary. Heh this kind of discussion is pretty usual when designing software solutions.

Comment: @DarshanMehta: I think you're missing the point of my problem. Actually I don't focus on the getButton(). It's just an example of how I tried to cheat around with using x in B.
The root problem is that x can be called many places in A and B, thus I don't think we can just "group" things to the getButton method like that :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract Button interface

   ```
   public interface Button {
       void init();
   }
   ```
2. Create PlainButton (your ex Button) class:

   ```
   public class PlainButton implements Button {
       public void init() {
           xx();
       }
       private void xx() {
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create IconButton class:

   ```
   public class IconButton implements Button {
       public void init() {
           yy();
           zz();
       }
       private void yy() {
       }
       private void zz() {
       }        
   }
   ```
4. Create ButtonWrapper class (your ex A and/or B classes):

   ```
   public class ButtonWrapper {
       private final T button;
       public ButtonWrapper(T button) {
           this.button = button;
           this.button.init();
       }
       public T getButton() {
           return button;
       }
   }
   ```
5. Use:

   ```
   ButtonWrapper A = new ButtonWrapper(new PlainButton());
   ButtonWrapper B = new ButtonWrapper(new IconButton());
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If your only concern is that `B` should have an `IconButton` instead of it's bases `Button`, why not create a separate member for it in B, and let A use that?

```
class A {
    protected Button b;
    public A() {
      // By default, I use a Button
      b = new Button();
    }

    // Subclasses can override which button I use
    protected A(Button b) {
       this.b = b;
    }

}

class B extends A {
    private IconButton ib;
    public B() {
      super(new IconButton());
      ib = (IconButton) super.b;
    }

    // B can access it's IconButton through ib
    // Users of A will see a Button
}
```

No need for an abstract base class, Generics, Wrappers. Just let B have it's IconButton, and have 2 references to it (`B.ib` and inherited `A.b`)

Comment: Ahhhhh... I forgot to mention that this is kind of a Component in my GWT app. So, if I declare like you said, then I'll have two buttons in my component ... (Or if I can live with yet another workaround, I can remove the original button in B. But it just becomes a whole new level of bad practice)

Comment: There is only 1 button when instantiating B. A never creates a button, when a subclass provides one. Or are you dealing with generated code and can't use this approach?

Comment: Woah.. seems like this is what I need. But does it look weird / introduce a bad practice here when we have two things (b and ib) that conceptually should just be one ?

I mean, your approach might be the best practically working one, but is it really a clean design ?

Comment: This is wrong. You cant pass `ib` to `super` constructor.

Comment: Well, there is the UML notation for Derived Attribute... I used this as a justification, but cannot say if it is really clean. The fixed version makes a bit clearer that `ib` is just a type-casted alias for `b`. So I'd say it's ok. Depends on your coding guidelines and standards, however...

Answer (score 0):

In case you dont want to use generics:
This approach goes against [best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342784/using-abstract-init-function-in-abstract-classs-constructor) but I find it totally fine as long as you dont do anything in `B`'s constructor with button:

```
public static class A {

    protected Button x = null;

    public A() {
        x = createButton();
    }

    public Button getButton() {
        return x;
    }

    protected Button createButton(){
        Button result = new Button();
        result.xx();
        return result;
    }
}

public static class B extends A{

    public IconButton getButton() {
        return (IconButton)x;
    }

    protected Button createButton(){
        IconButton iconButton = new IconButton();
        iconButton.yy();
        iconButton.zz();
        return iconButton;
    }
}
```

Now if you want to avoid cast you can use this crazy approach that I most likely would not use myself. **WARNING** use at your own risk:

```
public static class A {

        protected Button x = null;

        public A() {
            x = createButton();
        }

        public Button getButton() {
            return x;
        }

        protected Button createButton(){
            Button result = new Button();
            result.xx();
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A{

        //leave uninitialized so that when B gets constructed iconButton wont be reinitialized because it has been initialized by A's constructor call
        private IconButton iconButton; 

        public IconButton getButton() {
            return iconButton;
        }

        protected Button createButton(){
            iconButton = new IconButton();
            iconButton.yy();
            iconButton.zz();
            return iconButton;
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

As discussed the preferred way is to avoid inheritance in here and use composition if needed. But since the example code does not have much details in order to be able to show composition approach I am adding another approach that still uses inheritance, avoids cast and construction initialization.
I think it is best to use lazy initialization when working with non concurrent frameworks like Swing or GWT instead of construction initialization:

```
public static class A {

        private Button x = null;

        protected Button getButton() {
            if (x == null) x = createButton();
            return x;
        }

        private Button createButton(){
            Button result = new Button();
            result.xx();
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A{

        private IconButton iconButton; 

        public Button getButton() {
            if (iconButton == null) iconButton = createButton();
            return iconButton;
        }

        public IconButton getIconButton(){
            getButton();
            return iconButton;
        }

        private IconButton createButton(){
            IconButton iconButton = new IconButton();
            iconButton.yy();
            iconButton.zz();
            return iconButton;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually I don't just use x when in the constructor in B. In other words, there might be a ton of other methods in B that I'd like to invoke something special (from IconButton only). And so we'll just have to resort to my original workaround: invoking getButton() in all those places :(

Comment: You need to keep all `iconButton` initializing code inside `createButton()`.

Comment: yes I'm ok with initializing code in createButton(). But what if, say, I have a method B.handlerForEventXXX() that would need to invoke x.yy(). This is impossible => I have to invoke getButton().yy()... (I'm talking about your first approach). Please take a look at my updated code in the question.

Comment: Yes, you need to do casting of `x` or just call `getButton` in order to access `yy()`.

Comment: Yeah that's the whole point of my question.. I wonder if it's a really bad practice (as stated in @andre_stannek answer below) so I should better go with generics.

Comment: To be honest the whole B extends A thing is wrong in UI application like GWT. If you are extending them for code reuse then have separate abstract class that both A and B will extend from and you can use generics in order to avoid cast. But I would still use composition here instead of inheritance.

Comment: Sorry to make this conversation become too long, but could you make a sample code that uses composition ? I don't see any way that we can involve composition here (we are already using different types of Button inside different classes). Maybe it can become too complex for such a simple problem ?